# SELinux is preventing in:imjournal from unlink accesses on the file imjournal.state

Tags: linux, fedora, rsyslog, selinux

I have a problem on Fedora 36 with rsyslog, selinux and /var/log/messages components.

As you can see:

```
AVC avc:  denied  { unlink } for  pid=XXX comm="in:imjournal" name="imjournal.state" dev="XXX" ino=654207 scontext=system_u:system_r:syslogd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 trawcon="system_u:object_r:syslogd_var_lib_t:s15:c0.c1023".
```

Selinux is refusing access, and this is generating log message in /var/log/messages:

```
Nov 12 10:29:57 fedora setroubleshoot[262936]: 
Nov 12 10:30:13 fedora setroubleshoot[262957]: 
Nov 12 10:30:26 fedora setroubleshoot[262957]: 
Nov 12 10:30:38 fedora setroubleshoot[262957]: 
Nov 12 10:30:54 fedora setroubleshoot[263003]: 
Nov 12 10:30:59 fedora setroubleshoot[263003]: 
Nov 12 10:31:15 fedora setroubleshoot[263029]: 
Nov 12 10:31:28 fedora setroubleshoot[263029]:
```

and so on... so file /var/log/messages is getting bigger and bigger... that will cause hdd fill up very quickly... and also generating lots of alerts.

Other info:

```
 10:40:48 fedora rsyslogd[704]: imjournal: rename() failed for new path: '/var/lib/rsyslog/imjournal.state': Permission denied [v8.2204.0-2.fc36 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/0 ]
 10:41:01 fedora rsyslogd[704]: imjournal: rename() failed for new path: '/var/lib/rsyslog/imjournal.state': Permission denied [v8.2204.0-2.fc36 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/0 ]
 10:41:16 fedora rsyslogd[704]: imjournal: rename() failed for new path: '/var/lib/rsyslog/imjournal.state': Permission denied [v8.2204.0-2.fc36 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/0 ]
 10:41:22 fedora rsyslogd[704]: imjournal: rename() failed for new path: '/var/lib/rsyslog/imjournal.state': Permission denied [v8.2204.0-2.fc36 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/0 ]
```

ls -Zl /var/lib/rsyslog/imjournal.state

```
-rw-------. 1 root root system_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 121 10-08 12:42 /var/lib/rsyslog/imjournal.state
```

sealert:

```
Additional Information:
Source Context             system_u:system_r:syslogd_t:s0
Target Context             system_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0
Target Objects              imjournal.state [ file ]
Source                        in:imjournal
Source Path              in:imjournal
Port                          <Unknown>
Host                      fedora
Source RPM Packages          
Target RPM Packages          
Policy RPM selinux-policy-targeted-36.16-1.fc36.noarch
Local policy RPM   selinux-policy-targeted-36.16-1.fc36.noarch
Selinux Enabled         True
Policy Type                  targeted
Enforcing Mode               Enforcing
Host Name               fedora
Platform                     Linux fedora 5.15.70-xm1.0.fc36.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun
                              Sep 25 00:28:06 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64
Alert Count                44744
First Seen               2022-10-27 18:07:47 CEST
Last Seen                2022-11-12 10:44:37 CET
Local ID         67b7c558-292c-44d6-866b-a236712de092

Raw Audit Messages
type=AVC msg=audit(1668246277.176:46386): avc:  denied  { unlink } for  pid=xxx comm="in:imjournal" name="imjournal.state" dev="xxx" ino=654207 scontext=system_u:system_r:syslogd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 trawcon="system_u:object_r:syslogd_var_lib_t:s15:c0.c1023"


Hash: in:imjournal,syslogd_t,unlabeled_t,file,unlink
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The Target Context of `system_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0` is a likely cause. There may be a rule to allow `scontext=system_u:system_r:syslogd_t:s0` to perform actions on files of type `syslogd_var_lib_t`, which is what I think the SELinux context should be for the `/var/lib/rsyslog/imjournal.state` file. On my system, there's an fcontext rule that sets it:

```bash
/var/lib/r?syslog(/.*)?  all files  system_u:object_r:syslogd_var_lib_t:s0
```

The fix may be as simple as `restorecon -v /var/lib/rsyslog/imjournal.state`, followed up with a confirmation check of `ls -lZ /var/lib/rsyslog/imjournal.state`.

I don't have a Fedora system at-hand to confirm this, so you confirm the theory by checking the allowed actions between a source context of syslogd_t (shown in the audit) and a target context of syslogd_var_lib_t:

```
sesearch --allow -s syslogd_t -t syslogd_var_lib_t
```

as well as looking for fcontext rules:

```
semanage fcontext -l | grep 'syslog.*syslogd_var_lib_t'
```

If I'm correct, you'll see:

```
Found 8 semantic av rules:
...
   allow syslogd_t syslogd_var_lib_t : file { ioctl read write create getattr setattr lock append map unlink link rename open } ;
...
```

... in the sesearch output, and:

```
...
/var/lib/r?syslog(/.*)?                            all files          system_u:object_r:syslogd_var_lib_t:s0
...
```

... in the semanage output.

If you don't have the `sesearch` command by default, it should be available in an "setools" or "setools-console" package.

Comment: Thanks! When running 
`semanage fcontext -a -t system_u:object_r:syslogd_var_lib_t:s0 "/home/app/logs(/.*)?"`
I get
ValueError: Type system_u:object_r:syslogd_var_lib_t:s0 is invalid, must be a file or device type.

Comment: This worked: `semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_log_t "/home/app/logs(/.*)?"; restorecon /home/app`